# Puzzle on Reasoning

Tags: logic, puzzle

The following puzzle was introduced by the psychologist Peter Wason in 1966, and is one of the
most famous subject tests in the psychology of reasoning.

> Four cards are placed on the table in front of you. You are told
> (truthfully) that each has a letter printed on one side and a digit on
> the other, but of course you can only see one face of each. What you
> see is:
>
> ```
>                                                      B E 4 7
> ```
>
> You are now told that the cards you are looking at were chosen to
> follow the rule \If there is a vowel on one side, then there is an odd
> number on the other side." What is the least number of cards you have
> to turn over to verify this rule, and which cards do you in fact have
> to turn over?

My solution:

> Assuming A: Vowel on one side   B: Odd number on one side
>
> by the data given to us, A(conditional)B  {A implies B}. We have to
> verify this rule. We can do this by proving that the contrapositive of
> the above given statement is true, which says (NO ODD IMPLIES NO
> VOWEL). By doing this, We'll have to turn the "E" and the "4" card.

The correct answer is : "E" and "7" card.

Working:

> You need to turn over 2 cards (the E and the 7). The rule can be
> (simply) equivalently stated like so: There isn't a vowel on one side
> OR there is an odd number on one side. Thus, if you see a letter and
> it isn't a vowel, you don't need to verify the rule; likewise, if you
> see a number and it's odd, you don't need to verify the rule.

I have two concerns, 1. How is my reasoning wrong. and 2. How is the statement -"There isn't a vowel on one side OR there is an odd number on one side" equivalent to - "If there is a vowel on one side, then there is an odd number on the other side."

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wason_selection_task)  is on your side.

Comment: Not able to see the text in the grey area from an Android phone except in "desktop mode".

Comment: Also, please reword the sentence "The correct answer is..." since that's clearly wrong here. Maybe say "The book claims the correct answer is..." or something.

Answer (score 1):

The statements $(1)~V\implies O$ and $(2)~V'\cup O$ are equivalent. See the truth table:$$\begin{matrix}V&O&(1)&(2)\\0&0&1&1\\0&1&1&1\\1&0&0&0\\1&1&1&1\end{matrix}$$But you arrived at the correct answer. The book's explanation is also correct: since $B$ is not a vowel and $7$ is odd, these two cards already satisfy the rule. The ones you will need to check are, as you found out, $E,4$, to check whether the other side is having an odd number and non-vowel respectively. There seems to be a misprint.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer (not the book's) is correct. You are given a proposition that is a unidirectional implication $vowel \implies odd$. You need to test this by turning over any vowel card(s) you see to confirm the reverse side(s) is(are) odd(s).

But every implication also implies the contrapositive. Which means $not \ odd \implies not \ vowel$ which is equivalent to $even \implies consonant$. So you need to test this by turning over any even card(s) to confirm the reverse side(s) is(are) consonant(s).

In your set, that means only $E$ and $4$ need be turned over. The rest are irrelevant to the proposition.